# Thread.dispatchUncaughtException is being thrown, but I don't have any threads

Tags: java

I'm getting this error dispatchUncaughtException and I have no idea what that means, googling has been less than effective in answering what it is.  I consistently get it on the first run through of some code I wrote for a recursive interpolation search.

```
public static int interpolationSearch(int[] array, int target) {
    if (array.length < 4)
        return sequentialSearch(array, target);
    else {
        long numLeft = target - array[0];
        long numRight = array.length - 1;
        long numerator = numLeft * numRight;
        long denominator = array[array.length - 1] - array[0];
        int i = (int) Math.floor(numerator / denominator);
        //int i = (int)Math.floor(((target - array[0])*(array.length - 1))/(array[array.length - 1] - array[0]));
        if (target == array[i]) //center point is answer
            return i;
        if (target < array[i]) //recurse on left side
            return interpolationSearch(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, i),
                    target);
        //recurse on right side
        return i
                + interpolationSearch(
                        Arrays.copyOfRange(array, i, array.length), target);
    }
}
```

Any idea what's causing this error and how to fix it?  I've noticed that I'm consistently getting 0 for i which it shouldn't be by my calculations every time that it happens.

EDIT: Okay, so now I'm only getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException.  Although I didn't actually change anything so I'm kind of confused.  Somehow the math is coming out wrong although I don't know how.  If you know what the logic error is, please tell me, otherwise I'll just have to work it out.  I know what the deal is with this exception.

Comment: Include the stacktrace of the error you are getting. Also, you will always have at least one thread in your Java program.

Answer (score -2):

I think the reason you are getting 0 consistently is because of the if condition. You are checking for the condition where the length of the array is less than 4, if it is, you are calling the function again. Is the value of the array being changed at all?

Threads are assigned in Java for each process that runs. You are calling your function repeatedly so its safe to assume that a new thread assigned each time. Since there are limited number of threads in your thread pool, this might be causing the error as the recursion is never broken. If i have overlooked the fact of the array value being changed pls ignore this. :)

Comment: -1 The second paragraph is just wrong. You seem to have a misunderstanding of what threads are.